# No adapter for type Zend_Db_Table_Row error?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have a project in which I use more than one adapter.
So In ma models i created an abstract model

```
abstract My_Config1_Model extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract 
{

    public function init()
    {
     $db = Zend_Registry::get('dbcon')->getDb(Kiga_Data_Database::MASTER);
     $this->setDefaultAdapter($db);
    }

}
```

and then I inherit this abstaract class like:

```
class MyModel extends My_Config1_Model
{

        protected $_name = 'mytable';

 protected $_primary = 'id';

 protected $_rowClass = 'MyRow';

}


class MyRow extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract 
{

}
```

and the in my controller I try:

```
$table = new MyModel();
```

when I fetch alll it works:

```
$results = $table->fetchAll(); // works fine
```

but when I try to filter it it does not work:

results = $table->fetchRow("id = 1"); // Does not work. I get the error Error: No adapter for type MyRow.

Anybody any Idea?
Thanks.

I forgot I use also paginator

```
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($results);
```

Comment: Can you please post the content of the MyRow Class? Do you realy need an own implementation of the Row Class?

Comment: I just declared the class.
I guess there is no need for implementation. I just use it as row of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the place you should set the Db adapter for this table.

The `init()` method is called *after* the table class has parsed its options and set up the adapter for the table.  So all you've accomplished is to set the default Db adapter for *subsequent* table construction, but it has no effect on the *current* table if you do this in the `init()` method.

Consider this simplified example:

```
class MyTable
{
  static $defaultDb;
  protected $db;

  static function setDefaultDb($db) { self::$defaultDb = $db; }

  public function __construct() {
    $this->db = self::$defaultDb;
    $this->init();
  }

  public function init() {
    // Unfortunately, PHP allows you to run static methods 
    // as if they are non-static methods, which is confusing.  
    $this->setDefaultDb($globalDb);
  }
}
```

This example is a simplified model of the way `Zend_Db_Table` constructs.  Note that the `init()` method sets the class default Db, but this is run *after* the constructor has already set the instance Db to be the class default Db.  So setting the class default Db has no effect.

There are several ways you can set the Db adapter for a table:

- For all tables, using the static method `setDefaultAdapter()`.  The intended way to use `setDefaultAdapter()` is as follows:

  ```
  Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
  // now all tables will use $db by default
  $table = new MyModel();
  ```
- As a constructor argument:

  ```
  $table = new MyModel(array('db'=>$db));
  ```
- You might also be able to use the `setOptions()` method after the table class has been instantiated.

  ```
  $table = new MyModel(); // uses default Db
  $table->setOptions(array('db'=>$otherDb));
  ```

  But be aware that the table reads its metadata from the default Db during construction, so if you change the adapter subsequently, the table should be defined identically in both databases.